# What's the most concise way in Java to get the "Alpha" out of "AlphaSuffix"?

Tags: java, string

If I have a string such as one of the following:

```
AlphaSuffix
BravoSuffix
CharlieSuffix
DeltaSuffix
```

What is the most concise Java syntax to transform `AlphaSuffix` into **`Alpha`** into `BravoSuffix` into **`Bravo`**?

Comment: Are the possible suffices taken from a fixed list or merely everything up to the second upper case letter?

Comment: @Coggle Did you get an answer to your question? You didn't mark an accepted solution (green check).

Answer (score 4):

Chop it off.

```
String given = "AlphaSuffix"
String result = given.substring(0, given.length()-"Suffix".length());
```

To make it even more concise, create a utility method.

```
public static String chop(String value, String suffix){
    if(value.endsWith(suffix)){
        return value.substring(0, value.length() - suffix.length());
    }
    return value;
}
```

In the utility method, I've added a check to see if the suffix is actually at the end of the `value`.

---

Test:

```
String[] sufs = new String[] {
    "AlphaSuffix",
    "BravoSuffix",
    "CharlieSuffix",
    "DeltaSuffix"
};
for (int i = 0; i < sufs.length; i++) {
    String s = chop(sufs[i], "Suffix");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Gives:

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
```

Comment: I can't see this working. You don't know the size of the prefix unless you scan backwards to find the index, which you're not doing.

Comment: No probs :) I had a solution that involves much the same thing as you're doing, but it used indexOf, which realised was flawed. Ack :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple regexp to delete the suffix:

```
String myString = "AlphaSuffix";
String newString = myString.replaceFirst("Suffix$", "");
```

Comment: i think this is a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

if suffixes are all different/unkown you can use

```
myString.replaceFirst("^(Alpha|Bravo|Charlie|Delta|...).*", "$1");
```